# Why does the left shift on a unsigned int happens from the 16th bit?

Tags: c++11, binary, bit-manipulation

I am trying to put the values from the vector into the int.

> Given vector :'1','0','1','1','1','0','1','1','1','0','1','1','1','0','1','1' :

Expected output (binary representation for the variable out):

> 00000000000000001011101110111011.

However, I am getting the following output:

> 10111011101110110000000000000000

Notice: the insertion begun at the 16bit from right end instead of beginning from the leftmost bit

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

int main() {

   std::vector<unsigned char> test = {'1','0','1','1','1','0','1','1','1','0','1','1','1','0','1','1'};

   std::vector<unsigned int> out(1);

   int j = 0;

   for (int i =0; i < test.size(); i++) {
      out[j] = out[j] << 1;
      if (test[i] == '1') {out[j] |=0x1;}

   }

   j++;

   for (int p = 0; p < j; p++) {

      for (int k = 0; k<32; k++ ) {
         std::cout << !!((out[p]<<k)&0x8000);
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
   }

   std::cout << "Size Of:" << sizeof(int);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this happens is that you are using a wrong constant for the mask: `0x8000` has its 16-bit set, while you probably meant to use `0x80000000` with the 32-nd bit set. To avoid mistakes like that it's best to construct masks with shifts, for example

```
(1 << 31)
```

This expression is evaluated at compile time, so the result is the same as if you computed the constant yourself.

Note that both `0x8000` and `0x80000000` constants are system-dependent. Moreover, `0x80000000` assumes 32-bit `int`, which is not guaranteed.

A better approach would be shifting the number *right* instead of left, and masking with `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The block of code creating `out[j]` works just fine.

Your problem is in the output block, due to use of `0x8000`.  Whenever `k >= 16`, the low 16 bits will be zero, guaranteeing that `0x8000` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems overly complicated to me.  Here's my version of a C program that transforms a string of 1's and 0's into an int and one going from int to string.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv);

int main (int argc, char **argv)  {
   char str [] = "1010101010101010";

   int x;
   int out;
   for (x=0;x<16;x++)  {
      if (str[x] == '1') {
         out |= (1 << x);
      }
   }
   printf("%d", out) ;
}
```

and

```
   #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv);

    int main (int argc, char **argv)  {
       char str [] = "1010101010101010";

       int in = 21845;
       char out[17] = {0};
       for (x=0;x<16;x++)  {
          if (in & (1<<x)) {
             out[x] = '1';
          }
          else {
             out[x] = '0';
          }
       }
       printf("%s", out) ;
    }
```